# Receive "menu-toogle" event from section menu in customizer

Tags: javascript, theme-customizer, settings-api

I'm building a plugin that does some transformations on front page through JS script.

I'm trying to build a contextual control in the customizer so that when a certain section is opened I modify the view in iframe_

what's the correct listener  (and hook) for the section menu-toogle "open" event ?

Answer (score 0):

So far the only solution I've come up  with is creating a function  that `postMessage`s
the event into the iframe (using `customize_controls_enqueue_scripts` hook).

As for the receiver in iframe (hooked on `customize_preview_init` hook) I think it could still need some optimization because I'm getting a weird issue with `window.addEventListener('message',*` getting some duplicate on customizer loading..

But probably  it's the way it's supposed to work since i'm using the `customize_preview_init` hook twice.

Since I feel their might be better ways any feedback or comment is welcome_